# Vector based editing software for ArcMap .svg and .eps exports. Not Illustrator

Tags: image-editor, svg

I am looking for freeware software which I can use to touch up my maps after exporting from ArcMap.

There is just one PC where I work with Adobe Illustrator and I can hardly ever get on to it so I am looking for some free software (there is no chance that I'll be able to get my employer to pay) that can do a similar job to AI.

I will be using it to nudge around overlapping labels and features, tidy up legend items and manipulate colours in preparation to print.

I have done some research already and it seems that Inkscape (which I have some experience of using) isn't ideal but can it handle the relatively simple tasks that I have in mind. If not, can anyone recommend some freeware which can?

Comment: Check [this topic "Comparison of vector graphics editors"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_vector_graphics_editors) on Wikipedia. There are some solutions like Dia, Edraw Max, Embroidermodder, Inkscape, LibreOffice Draw, Macromedia FreeHand, Sketch, SVG-edit, Synfig. Personally, I am using Inkscape which by so far is the most deployed free software for vector graphics.

Comment: Note that this site is not about telling you if the software you've in mind can do what you want – it's the other way around: you say what the software you need should accomplish, and we recommend software that does. But for that we also need to know e.g. what OS it should run on :)

Comment: Izzy. 

I'm working on a Windows 7 P.C. with very low processing power. Maps will be outputted through ArcMap 10.2.2. 

The software will be mostly used to move feature labels around because ArcMap isn't very good at label placement no matter how much I play around with the settings in Maplex.

Unfortunately at my work any new software has to go through various layers of bureaucracy before it can be approved which is why I am asking for recommendations now as it isn't to download and trial software myself.

Thanks